# How to add width of every div if div is in ngFor?

Tags: angular

```
<div #elementView [style.width]="width+'px'" class="{{fixed ? 'fixed-div' : ''}}" *ngFor="let event of events">
    <header class="sticky"><span>{{event.datetime}}</span><span>{{event.date}}</span></header>
    <time-flow class="time-flow-child  z-table-view" *ngIf="event.event && !event.itemKey" [events]="event.event" [positions]="positions" [selected]="selected"></time-flow>
    <event-flow  class="z-col-24 nopadding z-event-cell" *ngIf="event.items" [events]="event.items" [positions]="positions" [selected]="selected"></event-flow>
</div>
```

My .ts file :

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
        if(this.elementView && this.elementView.nativeElement){
            this.width = this.elementView.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
            console.log(this.width,'aaaa');

        }

    }
```

I have this code. I want to add width for ever div his width. Right now it takes one width and added on all divs. Any suggestion how can i fix that?

EDIT:

I succesfully get width all divs like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.skillImgs.forEach((skill: ElementRef) => {
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(skill.nativeElement,'width',skill.nativeElement.offsetWidth);
   });

}
```

But i dont know how to pass them to div now. Any suggestion?

Comment: I can't imagine that.. can u attach image?

And what i can see is u get just one `width` in `ngAfterViewInit()` and You using it i every element but width should be set automatically.

Comment: every of divs have content inside and thats why they have different width ... so i want to get width of every div. I need to set size of dive because inside i have header that is position fixed and i want to set width to inherit to get width of div

Comment: `div his width` means what ?

Comment: i mean that div have some "automatically" width, and i want to get width of every div and added to style of that div. Div does not have fixed width..its based by content

Answer (score 1):

You can bind your div's width property to a method which will return width.

```
<div [style.width]="getElementWidth(event)" *ngFor="let event of events"></div>
```

**In your .ts class:**

```
getDivWidth(event:Event) { // event parameter is optional it could be blank as well
  // Return your appropriate width 
}
```